# Grails Geb: Chrome failed to start

Tags: grails, selenium-chromedriver, geb

I'm trying to set up geb functional testing in Grails, then I get "chrome failed to start". Could anyone help me out?

Exception Details:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf) on port 9374
Only local connections are allowed.
Failure:  |
unauthorized login to the home page(com.myapp.HomeFunctionalSpec)
 |
geb.driver.DriverCreationException: failed to create driver from callback 'script1426780645607568441896$_run_closure1@b0894c'
    at geb.driver.CallbackDriverFactory.getDriver(CallbackDriverFactory.groovy:35)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:80)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory$SimpleCache.get(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:30)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:79)
    at geb.Configuration.createDriver(Configuration.groovy:354)
    at geb.Configuration.getDriver(Configuration.groovy:343)
    at geb.Browser.getDriver(Browser.groovy:105)
    at geb.Browser.clearCookies(Browser.groovy:483)
    at geb.Browser.clearCookiesQuietly(Browser.groovy:491)
    at geb.spock.GebSpec.resetBrowser(GebSpec.groovy:45)
    at geb.spock.GebSpec.cleanup(GebSpec.groovy:67)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: chrome failed to start
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 586 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a6c4449dc285928ba024779344f5423c58', time: '2014-03-27 11:29:39'
System info: host: 'ILWS011', ip: '192.168.0.107', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.startSession(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:160)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:149)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:106)
    at script1426780645607568441896.run_closure1(script1426780645607568441896.groovy:5)
    at geb.driver.CallbackDriverFactory.getDriver(CallbackDriverFactory.groovy:29)
    ... 10 more
```

Below is the BuildConfig.groovy

```
def gebVersion = "0.9.2"
def seleniumVersion = "2.41.0"

dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
    ....
    test "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.3"
    test "org.gebish:geb-spock:$gebVersion"
    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:$seleniumVersion"
    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:$seleniumVersion"
}
plugins {
    // plugins needed at test environment
    test ":geb:$gebVersion"
}
```

test/functional/GebGonfig.groovy

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

driver = {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver//chromedriver.exe")
    new ChromeDriver()
}
```

I'm using the Chromedriver2.14, and putting it in `C:/chromedriver/`

Did I set everything right? Are the versions matching with each other?

Answer (score 1):

It's maybe because of old selenium Version. Use 2.45 and the newest webdriver.